# Select everything before & or everything if there is no &

Tags: regex

I want to use regex to split some text.

my text:
Hello&World
Hello
0011&World
0011

using `(.*)(\&.*)` only matches 'Hello&World' and '0011&World' and `(.*)(\&.*)?` ignores the last part.

For the first 2 I want to get 'Hello' and the last 2 I want to get '0011'

Thank you

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: pyhton, but I use https://regex101.com/ to check my regex

Comment: Are you just trying to split with `&`? [`s.split('&')`](https://ideone.com/esmjGP)?

Comment: I'm analyzing a lot of text so to have everything in regular expression would be nicer

Comment: What is the expected result for `hello&world&man`? It is a bit unclear: do you need to fetch 0+ chars other than `&` at the beginning of a string? Then you need `^[^&]*` - see the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Up7yNY/2).

Comment: If you just want to split at every `&` with a regex you can try to use this `([^&]*)` which matches everything but the `&` character?

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew  thats it. Thank you very much

Comment: try this `.+?(?=&|\Z)`. I've tried it here https://regex101.com/r/jC8nB0/128

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you need to fetch 0+ chars other than & at the beginning of a string.

Use the following regex:

```
^[^&]*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Up7yNY/2/).

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `[^&]*` - a [negated character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) matching zero or more (`*`) chars other than `&` (to match 1 or more replace `*` with `+`).

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/esmjGP):

```
import re
ss = ['Hello&World','Hello','0011&World','0011']
for s in ss:
    print(re.match('[^&]*', s).group())
    # print(re.search('^[^&]*', s).group())
```

Note that [`re.match`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match) looks for a match only at the start of the string, thus making `^` redundant in the pattern.

Else, if you use [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search), the `^` anchor is necessary to anchor the search at the start of the string.